# Autoresume mp3 on visiting different pages in website

Tags: html, flash, master-pages

I am using flash mp3 player on my master page. I want a music track to be played throughout website even if user visits different web pages without restart. I dont want to go with iframe. Also is there any way to store current play time of track from flash object to cookie and using this on reloading to start track from. If yes then how?

Comment: Pretty please don't have it play automatically...  you really should just use an iframe or popup window, it's really annoying to have any music on a webpage, nevermind music that stutters for a few seconds everytime you change pages...

Answer (score 0):

Cookies in Flash are called [Shared Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now my client changed his requirement because there were problems in popup window(some browsers bydefault blocks popup window) while in case of iframe, URL in address bar will not be shown or changed even if we visit another page.